# Iterating and conditionally hiding multiple elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery, visible, is-empty

```
if ( $("table tbody tr:visible").length === 0 ) { 
    $("table thead").hide();
} else {
    $("table thead").show();
}
```

I'd like to hide the `thead` element of all `table` elements that have a `tbody` with only hidden `tr` elements.
The code above works for one table, but not for multiple tables. I have lots of tables and this code searches for all `tbody tr` of all tables at once, instead of each table on its own.

Do I need to get `$("table").length` and check each for visible `tr`s? Is there a simpler solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also accomplish this without an explicit loop in your code. jQuery's `:has()` selector can take care of this for you in one line.

```
$("table:not(:has(tbody tr:visible)) thead").hide();
```

Using this, you can directly query all `thead` elements whose parent tables don't contain any visible `tr` elements within their `tbody`.

You can see this in action [here](https://jsfiddle.net/IronFlare/9o4qc16k/).

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Only came up with :not but has() was missing. Thanks a lot, I'll use this in my case.

Comment: The thead is also hidden, if the tbody has display:none, and not explicit all the tr has the display: none right? In both cases.. Just for future scenarios

Comment: @TimStieffenhofer Glad I could help! I've made a small edit to my code which satisfies the condition in your follow-up comment. By querying specifically for `tr:visible` *within* `tbody:visible`, a hidden `tbody` will satisfy the condition and hide its parent table's `thead`.

Comment: Actually, scratch that. It appears jQuery's `:visible` modifier cascades, so a hidden parent will also impart a hidden state on all of its children. My edit above is not necessary, so I've rolled it back. Using `:visible` does have some [slight performance implications](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/#visible1), so removing the second usage of it should, in theory, result in faster evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be able to identify the table you just processed. We can do so by using each:

```
$("table").each(){
   var myTable = $(this);  
   if ( myTable.find("tbody tr:visible").length === 0) { 
      myTable.find("thead").hide(); 
   } 
   else { 
      myTable.find("thead").show();  
   }
}
```